# codehunt 1.06 code puzzle has too many contingencies

Tags: c#, puzzle, solver

Even though I'm only at the beginning of this game where every level is kindergarten easy, I found myself stumped by this one problem. It was easy to solve but I can't figure out how to get all 3 points. It's obvious that my solution is quite ugly but the problem is also quite ugly and I can't think of a more elegant way to solve it.

The function is supposed to come up with expected results for predefined list of inputs. There doesn't seam to be a pattern so I had to wright 7 different return statements to cover all the scenarios. Can you figure out an elegant solution to this problem?

Here are my results, listing each of the expected results for each input:

```
X       EXPECTED RESULT     YOUR RESULT 
Success     29      0       0           
Success     4       1       1           
Success     -2      -2      -2          
Success     3       1       1           
Success     -4      -1      -1          
Success     2       2       2           
Success     -95     0       0           
Success     -1      -4      -4          
Success     1       4       4
```

Here's the ugly code I wrote to get the solution:

```
using System;
public class Program {
    public static int Puzzle(int x) {
        if (x==1) return 4;
        if (x==-1) return -4;
        if (x<-4 || x>4) return 0;
        if (x<-2) return -1;
        if (x<0) return x;
        if (x>3) return 1;
        return 4-x;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need further help I'll post the answer, but first a hint: note that it tells you to use the division operator (/) to solve the level.

Answer (score 1):

IGNORE THIS. It was way too obvious I guess but for some reason I decided to try something easy and it worked so I found the solution.

```
return 4/x;
```

Seriously. It was that easy.